# Delete content of dev/ folder by accident ~ Centos 6

Tags: linux

I have a dev folder in my www folder, and when I tried to copy it over to production, for some reason it seems I made a mistake and the content of the root-level dev folder got copied over.  I delete the live folder and replaced it with a back up I had.

I'm still connected via Putty, but restarting httpd doesnt work (source path '/dev/urandom' does not exist)

I can't connect to it again however, and I can't even transfer a database / file backup I've just made to another server.

On that picture you can see what I have left in the dev folder. The pic on the right is my other server, just used it for comparing.
http://screencast.com/t/I4XqjwR0

What would you do?

Comment: Off topic. Try on a linux stack.

Comment: Just as a side note: This nicely illustrates why you should not in general work as `root`, not even when deploying new code to your website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That might help

```
cd /dev
./MAKEDEV std
```

Comment: I'm getting 
-bash: ./MAKEDEV: No such file or directory
[root@server dev]# ./MAKEDEV std

Comment: But I see it at 
./sbin/MAKEDEV

Comment: i cp'ed to ../dev and then executed your command. Worked. THANKS A BUNCH MAN I FEEL SO HAPPY NOW YOU HAVE NO IDEA. By chance you're not in this room I'd turn gay

Comment: Then a mere `/sbin/MAKEDEV std` or even just `MAKEDEV std` should have helped; no need to copy it over.